# PatchCollection offset transform has odd behavior

Tags: python, matplotlib

The goal is to use `set_offset` to make the circle appear at position `(6,6)`:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_xlim(0, 12)
ax.set_ylim(0, 12)
r = plt.Circle((0,0), 3)
c = PatchCollection([r])
ax.add_collection(c)
# c.set_offset_transform(ax.transData)
# c.set_transform(ax.transData)
# c.set_offsets((6,6))
plt.show()
```

Produces what you'd expect:

[image]

Shifting it by `(6, 6)` seems to occur in display coordinates, and is barely discernable from the original image:

```py
c.set_offsets((6,6))  # <-- uncomment this line above
```

And changing the `PatchCollection`'s `offset_transform` or `transform` seems to have odd behavior:

```py
c.set_offset_transform(ax.transData) <-- new line
```

[image]

And using `c.set_transform(ax.transData)` produces an image that looks like the original.

Can anyone help me figure out how to update the circle coordinates from the patch collection api? I would prefer this since IRL I have a large collection of circles that I would like to update in one call. But if this isn't straightforward then I will look at updating the circles individually.